# Is it possible to make a recursive datatype in haskell that accepts more than one specific type?

Tags: list, haskell, types, type-parameter, recursive-datastructures

Say for instance I want to make a list type that allows for flexible nesting like so:

```
[[['a'],'a'],'a']
```

Would it be possible to implement this in haskell? How would I go about writing it's type signature? Any help would be awesome!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a list so much as a tree. As such you can represent it with a tree data type. One example is [the rose tree in `containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.2.1/doc/html/Data-Tree.html), whose definition is approximately:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
```

But maybe more suitable tree type in this case would be something like this (which is incidentally the [free monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.4.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Free.html) of `[]`; the rose tree is the [cofree comonad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/free/3.4.2/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html)):

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node [Tree a]
```

Using this type you could represent your  "list" like this, for example:

```
Node [Node [Node [Leaf 'a'], Leaf 'a'], Leaf 'a']
```

Comment: Hmmm.... would it be possible to combine the definitions of Lists and the Tree to make the Tree a Monoid (So that `mempty` would be List's `Empty`)?

Comment: I don't think I follow. If you're looking to get the syntax that you wrote above, that isn't really possible. If you want to make a `Monoid` instance for `Tree`, you can probably come up with something, but I'm not sure how it related to your question. If you want `[]` and `Tree` to be the same type, that's not possible. And there's nothing named `Empty` anywhere here. So I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Empty` as the value constructor from the `List` datatype explained in the LYAH book (Where `:` is replaced with `Cons`). Regardless, I think you're right, there's definitely a way to make `Tree` an instance of `Monoid`, but there's so many different ways to do it, it's not worth asking about haha. For instance, when defining `mappend` for two trees, how do they add up? Does the second tree become a child node of the lowest child of the first tree, or are they smushed together at each level of the heierarchy. Thank you for your feedback though!

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your own datatype with different value constructors.

From `ghci`:

```
Prelude> data Val a = Val a | List [Val a] deriving (Show)
Prelude> [List [List [Val 'a']], Val 'a']
[List [List [Val 'a']],Val 'a']
```

And its type:

```
Prelude> :t [List [List [Val 'a']], Val 'a']
[List [List [Val 'a']], Val 'a'] :: [Val Char]
```

Also, checkout how JSON is represented in Real World Haskell: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html
(search for `data JValue` to find the relevant data type)